# parse file and add value in dictionary , Python 3.5

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to read score of each char from file and add it as key and value in dictionary , in python 3.5

## This the code

```
def read_score_file(score_dic):
    #open file
    f = open ('AA_score_file.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
            #split current line 
            #1st part is Key = char
            #2nd part is value = score 
            score_dic.append(line.split())

    f.close()
    print (score_dic)
```

## while the text file contain

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

Comment: Okay. What's your actual question?

Comment: This code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line.split() returns an array, you could assign it to key values.

```
(key, value) = line.split()
score_dic[key] = value
```

Comment: it gave me this message :  RESTART: C:\Users\rana\Desktop\read score fun.py .
even i restarted everything

Answer (score 0):

To create the dictionary from scratch:

```
with open('AA_score_file.txt') as f: 
    score_dic = dict(map(str.split, f))
print(score_dic)
```

Or, to update an existing dictionary:

```
with open('AA_score_file.txt') as f: 
    score_dic.update(dict(map(str.split, f)))
print(score_dic)
```

Comment: give me this error too ..  RESTART: C:\Users\rana\Desktop\read score fun.py . even i restarted everything